# How to add and remove same fragment frequently

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

My application usually add and then remove the same fragment many times. Below is how I do this:

`Add fragment`

```
if (mHomeFragment == null)
    {
        mHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.dummy, mHomeFragment).commit();
            }
        }, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.transition_duration));
    }
else
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.dummy, mHomeFragment).commit();
    }
```

`Remove fragment`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mHomeFragment).commit();
```

Problem is, sometime my app has crashed when navigate from the activity contains that fragment (HomeFragment) to another activity. I tried to figure out why but still no way. I have no full error-log here because this error doesn't happen often, but the error is same like this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/5506618c80a292ac275d8b0c1046b446c7f58836%5E!/:

```
IllegalStateException: Failure saving state......active HomeFragment{419494f0} has cleared index: -1
```

Does anyone see any problem with my code or just know how to fix this error, please help me. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think when you remove the fragment that you will want to add back later, you need to include a .addToBackStack("name") in the transaction, and when later you want to add it back, call FragmentManager.popBackStack() to undo the removal

Comment: I will give it a try, but because this error does not happen often so I can't tell you if this error still happen now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the runnable might be running after the activity was paused or finished. Just make sure to call handler.removeCallback on the activity onPause method to avoid the callback to the activity once it's done.

If you need to swap fragments often, you can use the FragmentTransaction [hide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide%28android.app.Fragment%29) and [show](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show%28android.app.Fragment%29) methods so you avoid the initialization overhead.

Comment: I'm sure that error is not by the Handler because my fragment always be added before going to new activity. I also tried to use hide and show fragment but it does not work in my case. Anyway, thank for your answer.

Comment: How do you initialize the fragments without being in the activity that host them ?